# enhanced wiki functionalities in microsoft teams?

Tags: wiki, microsoft-teams

I am looking for ways to have enhanced wiki-functionalities in Teams:

- templates
- structured metadata
- tagging

Is there an "app store" where I search look for something like this ?
Is it possible to extend the existing wiki feature?
How complicated is it? Is there a "hello world" or Basic Tutorial?

Or is all this already possible and I just don't know how?

Comment: Wiki is a Tab published by Microsoft. You can build a tab of your own. Please start here: [Add tabs to Microsoft Teams apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview).

Comment: Thanks that looks like integrating an existing wiki software - but then we'd provably loose User-Management, comments, watching and the like.

Comment: (Not really a Stack Overflow question.) No, there isn’t anything in the app store that has features like this at this time.