# How can I integrate Mediawiki with MS Teams (or other collaboration software)?

Tags: mediawiki, microsoft-teams, mediawiki-extensions

This is a follow-up question to [enhanced wiki functionalities in microsoft teams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429497/enhanced-wiki-functionalities-in-microsoft-teams) where a comment recommends to integrate a special tab for enhanced wiki-functionalitites in teams.

If we integrate MW as an inline "tab" in teams, then I'd like to integrate the collaboration features like:

- mention
- subsriptions
- comment / chat / discuss

I would assume that both platforms can be extended properly.

1) "Events" in MW should be published to Teams. What "hooks" do these platforms provide? How much effort is it to integrate them? Precondition: same user-management is used - how?

2) How could a "persistent teams chat" be integrated into / replace the "discuss this page" feature?

Thanks for any hints / approaches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capabilities you reference used by the Wiki tab are not yet available to external developers. We plan to expose them at some point but do not have further information regarding dates or specifics.

Comment: Wiki functionality in SharePoint / teams was always weak - please enhance it - it is a collaboration booster.